# iOS Autolayout: Align left edge of a UILabel with horizontal center in container?

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

So I'm trying to have a customized UITableViewCell that looks like the following:

[image: See the second column of titles and how the left side of them are aligned with the center]

And I'm trying to get the Detail labels to be left aligned and set the content hugging on the title labels higher.

So the challenge I have is that I want the left edge of the second column on Title cells to be aligned with the center of the whole view.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a couple of grouping views, one for each column. Pin the outer edges of each column view to the edges of the cell content view, then add an equal-widths constraint to the column views.

Once you have your containing column views in place, you can layout the labels inside each.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It did work... :) @darren102 also mentioned embedding it in another view makes this possible.

Answer (score 2):

Add equal widths constraint, add leading space constraint to left view, and trailing space to the right, and horizontal spacing between them.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could put them in a UIView and that views left edge would be equal to CenterX and thus they would be aligned in the middle. Or you could just align the top title cell to CenterX and have the leading edge of each title match that. There are numerous ways you can achieve what your asking here.

```
NSLayoutContraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];

NSArray *constraints [NSLayoutConstraint
                      constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[label1]-(5)-[label2]-(5)-[label3]|"
                      options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading
                      metrics:nil
                      views:@{ @"label1" : label1, @"label2" : label2, @"label3" : label3 }];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

Above is just samples of how you could do it in the code if you wished too, self.view is a view but if you wanted the content view of the UITableViewCell you could just switch it out to that.

Comment: Thanks @darren102! The idea of putting them in separate UIView did the job. I picked @lintmachine as the right answer because it was more visual.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the suggestions above working so I did this another way.

- InnerView1 50% width of ContentView & pinned to left
- InnerView2 50% width of ContentView & pinned to right

Simple.